# Qt colliding selection boxes

Tags: qt

this app draws some graphic items with the flags ItemIsMovable and ItemIsSelectable.
The QGraphicsView handles all keyboard and mouse interaction.

I would like to always select the smallest item in surface, if two boundingRects() collide; as an example, imagine two rectangles, one inside the other. The user clicking the inside rectangle will expect that one to be selected.

My ideas :

(1) Recalculate Z-indexes each time an item changes shape. It seems a little overkill.

(2) Reimplementing QGraphicsItem.shape() [ my items are actually segment paths - if I could get a selection over the segments and not over the bounding box, it would work ] - returning the QPainterPath() didn't seem to do the trick.

(3) Catch mouse events inside items first and do something (?) to override the default selection mechanism. It also seems overkill.

Is there an easy way to achieve this goal?

Thanks,
Sébastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user selects an item and the graphics view receives the position, you can use the position, [convert it to scene coordinates](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#mapToScene) and call [QGraphicsScene::items](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#items-3) function. This will return the items at the given position.

Now you have the list of items at the point the user selected, you can then compare the items to find the smallest and [set it as selected](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setSelected).

Comment: Thansk for your answer; how does the QGraphicsView receive the position of the click that triggered a selection. That is kind of my probleme, I have no idea how the standard selection mechanism is hookable. There is the QGraphicsScene.selectionChanged() signal but it doesn't have parameters - I would need to get a global mouse position and convert it to scene if I went that route. Is there maybe a simpler way?

Comment: Inherit from QGraphicsView and then use the mouse event functions; mousePressEvent mouseMoveEvent mouseReleaseEvent. If you don't want to subclass QGraphicsView, you could create a class inherited from QObject, override its mouse event functions and set it as an event filter on the QGraphicsView instance.

Comment: I already have a derived class, which overloads press, move and release mouse events. What I don't understant is how to link the mouseEvent and the selectionEvent. On one side I receive selectionChanged in the scene, and forward it to the view, on the other side I receive mouseEvents, but I don't receive them at once. Or do you mean I can get selection information from mouse events? I am gonna look at that.

Comment: In the mouse events, you call QGraphicsScene::items which gives you the list of items at the given position. Using this list of items, calculate the smallest item and set it as selected by calling its setSelected function. You do not need the selectionChanged function here. If this is not clear, perhaps I misunderstand what you're asking.

Comment: Oh! I was hellbent on finding a complicated solution; this looks much more logical; thanks again.